# Writer/math student seeking an overview of linguistics. Help?

Tags: historical-linguistics, computational-linguistics, reference-request

I am a math and statistics student/enthusiast as well as a fiction writer with cultivated interest in a few foreign languages. Linguistics has held appeal to me for many years, but I admit to having only had a cursory introduction to the field.

Lately I have been searching for an access point and quite naturally turned to [*The Algebraic Theory of Context-Free Languages*](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~berstel/Mps/Travaux/A/1963-7ChomskyAlgebraic.pdf) by Noam Chomsky and Marcel-Paul Schützenberger. I assume that reading this text is, at this point in time, as much like reading history as it is like reading linguistics, but I have been stimulated nonetheless, especially by all the possibilities of connecting algebra and linguistics.

My questions are the following:

- What other (past or current) papers are worth reading *for a non-linguist* to develop an adequate view of the linguistic landscape?
- In your opinion, what are some linguistic papers/ideas/schools of thought that might interest someone who is part-mathematician, part-humanist?
- For the linguists out there: is there a book or paper about linguistics that you wish everyone in society would read?

Also, one more (possibly too esoteric) question:

- Does anyone know of applications of [*Gröbner bases*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis) in (computational) linguistics?

Thanks so much for humoring the questions of an outsider. I look forward to your responses!

Nathan

Comment: You might find Jim McCawley's _The Syntactic Phenomena of English_ a decent roadmap to some areas of data-driven syntactic theory, and his companion _Everything Linguists Have Always Wanted to Know about Logic (But Were Ashamed to Ask)_ for the relations among logic, semantics, pragmatics, and syntax. Both are from University of Chicago Press.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for a good beginners reference to learn computational linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1320/looking-for-a-good-beginners-reference-to-learn-computational-linguistics)